# Ruby on Rails - javascript table filtering doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a strange problem. My filtering table doesn't work as it should. Here is javascript function that is activated the moment select value is changed.

```
function filterTable(opt, coln, tbId){
    var filter = opt.value.toLowerCase(),
      table = document.getElementById(tbId),
      trs = table.getElementsByTagName("TR"),
      col = table.querySelector('th[title='+coln+']').cellIndex,
      x;
    for (var i = 1; i < trs.length; i++){
      x = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("TD")[col];
      if(x){
        classes = trs[i].classList;
        classes.remove(coln+'-filtered-active');
        classes.remove(coln+'-filtered-hidden');
        if(filter){
          console.log('tekst:' + x.textContent.length + ' ' + x.textContent +' || filter:' + filter);
        if (x.textContent.toLowerCase() == filter) {
          classes.add(coln+'-filtered-active');
        }
        else {
          classes.add(coln+'-filtered-hidden');
        }
          }
          trs[i].style.display = "";
        for(var k=0; k < classes.length; k++){
          if(classes[k].includes('filtered-hidden')) {
            trs[i].style.display = "none";
            break;
          }
        } 
      }   
    } 
  }
```

Here is rendered (I'm working in Rails) html structured containing one of the cells that belongs to the column I want to sort by.

```
<td>
   <div class="cardLabel feature">feature</div>
</td>
```

The thing is x.textContent returns not only feature but also newlines and whitespaces that amounts to 55 characters. I believe that's why my filtering method doesn't work. But I have no idea how to solve this problem.This is the way how I get data to the view:

```
        <tbody>
              <% @cards.each do |card| %>
                <tr>
                  <td>
                    <%= card[:card_name].truncate(50) %>                        
                  </td>
                  <td>
                    <div class="cardLabel <%= card[:label_name].gsub(/\s+/, "").downcase %>"><%=card[:label_name].upcase %></div>
                  </td>
                   <td><%= card[:time_from]+'-'+card[:time_to]+'h' %></td>
                  <td><%= card[:list_name] %></td>
                  <td><%= card[:organization_name] %></td>
                  <td><%= card[:board_name] %></td>
                </tr>
              <% end %>
            </tbody>
```

Comment: Currently problem was solved by calling trim() on x element. It helps but I would like to prevent that problem befote it gets to filtering function.

Comment: Can you show what is currently returned as x and what's in card?

Answer (score 0):

Try `innerText`. From the code you posted `innerText` and `textContent` should be the same. But I assume you have other codes that add other elements that are not displayed but are picked up by `textContent`

https://jsfiddle.net/msyLm8u2/

Comment: It didn't work :/ Maybe the proble is how i get this data. Code added to post.

Comment: From your code, `card` is not an instance variable? You are sure the rendered HTML is just `<div class="cardLabel feature">feature</div>`?

Comment: card is loop scoped variable. @cards is instance variable. Whole code updated